# How to capture output of exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use the `exec-maven-plugin` as a way to integrate a 3rd party Java API.  I'm using the `exec:java` goal to call my java main class.  I need to parse the output of the API, however I do not see anything specific in the plugin that allows for this.

Is there a way in maven and/or the exec-maven-plugin to capture/save the output of the executions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [`exec:exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal, you can use the `outputFile` parameter (or using the command line property `exec.outputFile`).

Comment: Thanks.  I should have specified that I was using the `exec:java` goal.  If desperate, I guess I can use the `exec:exec` goal if noone else has another solution available.

Comment: `exec:java` runs within the current JVM as the Maven build. You can always fork `java` with the `exec:exec` goal.